# How to read date values seperated with slash from csv files with pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hello I want to read date values seperated with `/` in csv file and convert it datetime format in python. In this example my date values `day/month/year/hour/minute/second` under the `Tarih` column:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this.

```
import datetime

# 1st argument: actual date 
# 2nd argument: format of date
mDate = datetime.datetime.strptime("1/1/2012/1/1/1", "%d/%m/%Y/%H/%M/%S")
print(mDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter format define in http://strftime.org/:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Tarih'], format='%d/%m/%Y/%H/%M/%S')
print (df)
            Tarih          Veri                date
0  1/1/2012/1/1/1   6.028350798 2012-01-01 01:01:01
1  1/1/2012/1/1/2  7.072969987  2012-01-01 01:01:02
2  1/1/2012/1/1/3   1.76o4o2oes 2012-01-01 01:01:03
3  1/1/2012/1/1/4  -3.345437166 2012-01-01 01:01:04
4  1/1/2012/1/1/5  -5.209516549 2012-01-01 01:01:05
5  1/1/2012/1/1/6  -3.730161144 2012-01-01 01:01:06
6  1/1/2012/1/1/7  -10.80188385 2012-01-01 01:01:07
```